# Close shapes in Inkscape for Lightburn fill

Tags: inkscape, fill

I have created an svg in Inkscape. I then import this svg into [LightBurn](https://lightburnsoftware.com/).
In order to do a fill in Lightburn all the vectors have to be closed.
In this case it thinks that there are 9 shapes in the svg that are not closed. These are all in the stem/leaf part of the logo. The circle/arrows are not a problem.

How to I close these shapes in Inkscape?

[File here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1clO5ViIC0ncBBY0vGO34pS8lYud2R4Bg/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the two end points of an open path using the Edit Paths by Nodes Tool (N), and hit the Join Selected Nodes button.

Example

[image]